# Get Text string and tag from TupleView/ForEach using reflection

Tags: swift, swiftui

Given a TupleView and ForEach containing `Text(...).tag(...)`:

```
// TupleView
Text("Zero").tag(0)
Text("One").tag(1)
Text("Two").tag(2)

// ForEach
let values: [String] = ["Zero", "One", "Two"]
ForEach(values.indices, id: \.self) { index in
    Text(values[index]).tag(index)
}
```

How do I reflect back the `.tag(...)` and inner `Text(String)` value?

I want to build a custom Picker-like View. Apple's Picker is able to find the matching Text based on selection and preview the selected value.

Answer (score 1):

Using Mirror and extensions on ForEach and TupleView:

```
import SwiftUI

func getTaggedText<Tag: Hashable, Content: View>(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) -> [(Tag, String)] {
    guard let gettable = content() as? GetTaggedText else {
        return []
    }
    return gettable.getTaggedText()
}

print(getTaggedText {
    Text("Zero").tag(0)
    Text("One").tag(1)
    Text("Two").tag(2)
} as [(Int, String)])

let values: [String] = ["Zero", "One", "Two"]
print(getTaggedText {
    ForEach(values.indices, id: \.self) { index in
        Text(values[index]).tag(index)
    }
} as [(Int, String)])

//
// All the reflection code
//

protocol GetTaggedText {
    func getTaggedText<Tag: Hashable>() ->  [(Tag, String)]
}

// view: The modified Text(...).tag(...) view
func extractTaggedText<Tag: Hashable>(_ view: Any) -> (Tag, String)? {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: view)
    // Get the tag trait
    guard let tag = mirror.descendant("modifier", "value", "tagged") as? Tag else {
        return nil
    }
    // Unwrap Text(...) from tag trait
    guard let text = mirror.descendant("content") as? Text else {
        return nil
    }
    let textMirror = Mirror(reflecting: text)
    // get String from Storage -> String
    if let string = textMirror.descendant("storage", "verbatim") as? String {
        return (tag, string)
    }
    // get String from Stroage -> LocalizedStringKey
    if let string = textMirror.descendant("storage", "anyTextStorage", "key", "key") as? String {
        return (tag, string)
    }
    return (tag, "")
}

extension TupleView: GetTaggedText {
    func getTaggedText<Tag: Hashable>() ->  [(Tag, String)] {
        guard let tuple = Mirror(reflecting: self).descendant("value") else {
            return []
        }
        let values = Mirror(reflecting: tuple)
        let count = values.children.count
        var result: [(Tag, String)] = []
        for index in 0..<count {
            // Get individual View within tuple
            guard let view = values.descendant(".\(index)") else {
                break
            }
            guard let taggedText: (Tag, String) = extractTaggedText(view) else {
                continue
            }
            result.append(taggedText)
        }
        return result
    }
}

extension ForEach: GetTaggedText where Content: View {
    func getTaggedText<Tag: Hashable>() ->  [(Tag, String)] {
        var result: [(Tag, String)] = []
        for v in data {
            let view = content(v)
            guard let taggedText: (Tag, String) = extractTaggedText(view) else {
                continue
            }
            result.append(taggedText)
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Results of prints:

```
[(0, "Zero"), (1, "One"), (2, "Two")]
[(0, "Zero"), (1, "One"), (2, "Two")]
```

(Sources that helped me figure this out: [this post](https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/inspecting-views/) and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nerdsupremacist/ab8d7909ec38eab5a06fb1ee0508ae38)).